# XMLHttpRequest tipo DELETE Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, delete, xmlhttprequest

Estoy usando Laravel y quiero hacer eliminar un registro, para esto estoy usando una peticion XMLHttpRequest, el problema es que, como estoy usando las rutas por medio de 'Resource' (`Route::resource('/url',Controller::Class);)`

Pues para acceder al método 'Destroy' me pide que envie los parametros con el metodo DELETE desde la vista, y no se como hacerlo con las peticiones XMLHttpRequest, recordando a Ajax intente hacer esto, pero no funcionó

```
const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = "/Medicos/" + id ;
const type = 'DELETE';
            http.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    let Medico = this.responseText;
                    console.log(Medico);
                }
            };
            http.open("GET", url);
            http.send();
```

Tambien intente cambiar el

```
http.open('DELETE', url);
```

Pero me arroja este error

```
DELETE http://moon.project/Medicos/2 419 (unknown status)
```

Comment: ¿Probaste usando [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)?

Comment: La verdad es que no lo conocía, voy a leerme la documentación, en caso de no encontrar otra solución. Voy a probar fetch mientras tanto a ver si con eso lo soluciono, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La petición tiene que ser `POST` y tendrás que enviar un campo `_method` con valor `DELETE`. Además, como en todas las peticiones `POST`, tienes que enviar también un campo `_token` con el `csrf_token` de tu aplicación.

Eso lo puedes meter en un objeto `FormData` por ejemplo:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("_method", "delete");
formData.append("_token", "{{ csrf_token() }}");// sólo en blade

const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = "/Medicos/" + id;

http.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        let response = this.responseText;
        console.log(response);
    }
};
http.open("POST", url);
http.send(formData);
```

Si no estás haciendo la llamada en una plantilla blade, puedes agregar el token a una etiqueta `<meta>` dentro la etiqueta `<head>` de la plantilla blade principal de tu aplicación:

```
<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Y al `token` lo puedes obtener de ahí:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("_method", "delete");
let token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
formData.append("_token", token);

const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = "/Medicos/" + id;

http.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        let response = this.responseText;
        console.log(response);
    }
};
http.open("POST", url);
http.send(formData);
```

Ref. XMLHttpRequest: [Métodos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open()).
Ref. Laravel: [Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#form-method-spoofing).